# How to change the attributes of window in Titanium studio

Tags: uitableview, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have created an app using Titanium Studio.I'm using tableview to display the contents of my database and now i want to customise my window completely.
for eg: i want to change the nav bar completely with some cool back buttons...and i also want to display an image just over my tableview(if possible) can anyone pls help me out? 
And for reference u can see the app named Zomato on app store or google play...just the kind of customisation I want for my app... Thanx in advance

I've tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
var titleView = Titanium.UI.createView({
backgroundColor :'#000000',
layout : 'Vertical'
});

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
rightNavButton: titleView,
title:'Cars',  
backgroundColor:'#fff',
tabBarHidden : true,
backButtonTitleImage:'image.jpg',
url:'db.js',

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a back button for your application, simply create a button and set the `backgroundImage` property and add it to the window as follows

```
var btnBack = Ti.UI.createButton({
    left      : 3,
    height    : 30,
    width     : 70,
    top       : 5,
    backgroundImage : 'image.jpg'
});

win.add(btnBack);
```

This will add the back button in your app.